# How Can I check image size and resize it in Django

Tags: python, django

I am working on a Django project where I want to check uploaded image size if it is more than 14kb, and resize it to be less than or equal to 14kb. My code below does the other checks but doesn't work on reducing the image size to be less than or equal to 14kb. So the image is been uploaded with the original size. Someone help with the best way using my code below. Understand that using django-imagekit could help me with all I needed while processing the image because of the implementation process.

```
  def clean_image(self):
    image = self.cleaned_data.get('image')

    if image:
        # Check if the image size exceeds 14kb
        if image.size > 14 * 1024:  # 14kb in bytes
            # Open the image using Pillow
            with Image.open(image) as img:
                # Resize the image while preserving the aspect ratio
                max_size = (img.width, img.height)
                img.thumbnail(max_size)

                # Rotate the image if it's originally landscape
                if img.width > img.height:
                    img = img.transpose(Image.ROTATE_90)

                # Convert the image to RGB mode
                img = img.convert('RGB')

                    # Save the modified image to a BytesIO object
                buffer = BytesIO()
                img.save(buffer, format='JPEG')

                 # Create a new InMemoryUploadedFile object with the modified image data
                modified_image = InMemoryUploadedFile(
                    buffer,
                    None,
                    'modified.jpg',  # Specify the desired filename
                    'image/jpeg',  # Specify the content type
                    buffer.tell,
                    None
                )

            # Replace the original image object with the modified image
            self.cleaned_data['image'] = modified_image

        # Check file extension for allowed formats
        allowed_formats = ['gif', 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'png']
        ext = image.name.split('.')[-1].lower()
        if ext not in allowed_formats:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Only GIF, JPEG, PNG and JPG images are allowed.")

        # Check if the image is still set to the default 'avatar.jpg'
        if image.name == 'avatar.jpg':
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please upload a different image before submitting the form.")

    return image
```